# Transmit object with getter/setter property via HttpClient

Tags: angular, getter-setter, angular-httpclient

I have the following class:

```
export class FileData {
  get name(): string { return this.#name || (this.data ? `Unnamed.${this.data.match(/[^:/]\w+(?=;|,|\+)/)?.[0]}` : '') }
  set name(name: string) { this.#name = name; }
  #name: string = '';

  public data: string;

  constructor(name: string, data: string) {
    this.name = name;
    this.data = data;
  }
}
```

I'm creating an object of this class, which I then try to submit to a mongoose api via angular's http:

```
this.value = new FileData("xyz", "abc");
this._http.post<FileData>(targetUrl, this.value, { observe: 'response' })
```

What I would expect to happen is a request payload like this:

```
{
  data: "abc",
  name: "xyz"
}
```

However, the name property does not exist in the payload. I can access the property in the dev-tools and see the file name, but it won't be sent in the http request. How can I make angular treat this getter/setter property as if it was a regular property and include it in my http payload?

If instead of the #name I define it as `private _name: string`, then the payload will contain the private property _name next to the data property, but also only that, which I do not want.

Comment: Is there any special reason why you would need to instantiate an object of `FileData` type rather than having a simple interface `FileData`? Additionally, why do you not want to use `private` in a `Typescript` project?

Comment: @Andres2142 As you can see, I'm returning a placeholder "filename" in case it is unknown. I'm uploading a file through a user interaction, which will have to instantiate an object eventually. If I use an interface, I'll just have to instantiate it further down the line. I don't mind using private in a typescript project. The issue is that the private property name is `_name`, and not `name`, because the latter is the getter and setter. So when I transmit the object, I'll transmit one with the private `_name` property and not the intended `name` property the database expects.

Comment: @Andres2142 This is just an example, btw. I'm not actually doing this. This object comes from an input form, but for the sake of ease and not having to include plenty of other components, services, templates, I just chose to write it as initiation, because it makes no difference to the issue.